# Help please with manually reinstalling some 'purged' packages in the right order to get back my network connection

Tags: apt

I removed packages I shouldn't have after using 'purge' to remove isc-dhcpd-server, isc-dhcpd-client and isc-dhcpd-common. Of the last two Iḿ actually wondering if I should have had them removed at all (I used isc-dhcpd to network-install wattOS (ubuntu 13.04 alternative) on an old laptop without cd-rom or USB boot, and after having finished I wanted to remove isc-dhcpd again..)

Along with the above stuff I managed to remove the following packages according to the /var/.../dpkg.log file:

```
ubuntu-minimal:i386 1.307
network-manager-gnome:i386 0.9.8.0-1ubuntu5.1
network-manager:i386 0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22
dnsmasq-base:i386 2.66-4ubuntu1
iputils-arping:i386 3:20121221-1ubuntu1
libgnome-bluetooth11:i386 3.8.1-2ubuntu2
libnetfilter-conntrack3:i386 1.0.3-1
libmnl0:i386 1.0.3-3
libnm-glib-vpn1:i386 0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22
libnm-gtk0:i386 0.9.8.0-1ubuntu5.1
libnm-glib4:i386 0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22
libnm-gtk-common:all 0.9.8.0-1ubuntu5.1
libnm-util2:i386 0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22
wpasupplicant:i386 1.0-3ubuntu2.1
libreadline5:i386 5.2+dfsg-2
```

Can somybody maybe help me by explaining how to manually reinstall them *in the right order*? I guess that if I start with the right ones (DNS, network manager, wpasupplicant) I should have my wireless connection back up and running, so that the rest might be a bit easier to finish in the command-line. I did try to google around a bit to find a solution, but I guess my problem is rather unique.

Just to be clear wattOS is running fine and I can use USB-sticks to get the packages on the specific PC, just the network is down due to the removed packages so I can do it with apt-get.

Maybe somebody can also explain me how to install the packages that I 'import' by means of the USB-stick.. I guess pcmanfm to open the folder, than saying 'open current folder in terminal' and then some magic with dpkg, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest way to repair that would be to :

1. Download all packages from `packages.ubuntu.com`
2. Install them with the command :

   `sudo dpkg -i NAME_OF_THE_PACKAGE`
3. If by misfortune, a package is missing, download it and restart from step 2.

---

**1. Download all packages** (click on `i386` at the end of each page)

- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/wpasupplicant
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libmnl0
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libnm-gtk-common
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libnetfilter-conntrack3
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/ubuntu-minimal
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/network-manager
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/network-manager-gnome
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/dnsmasq-base
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/iputils-arping
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libgnome-bluetooth11
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libnm-glib-vpn1
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libnm-gtk0
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libnm-glib4
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libnm-gtk-common
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libnm-util2

**2. Copy the packages** to a new directory in your HOME (for example `~/packages`)

**3. Open a terminal** (CTRL-ALT-T) and go to the directory containing the packages :

```
cd ~/packages
```

**4. Install them** with this command (it's in the right order): 
*NOTE: `*` will automatically be replaced by the right name.*

```
sudo dkpg -i limbn-util2* libnm-glib-vpn1* libnm-glib4* libnm-gtk-common* libnm-gtk0* libmnl0* libnetfilter-conntrack3* dnsmasq-base* iputils-arping* libgnome-bluetooth11* libreadline5* wpasupplicant* ubuntu-minimal* network-manager* network-manager-gnome*
```

**5. Run apt-get** to check if it's installed. :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You may have to do this command, if asked :

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

**6. Reboot your PC** and try to connect.

**7. If you are connected**, run the upgrade command to update your system :

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

---

**How did I knew the right order ?**

- Do a LIST of the needed packages.
- Go to `package.ubuntu.com` .
- Find the packages you are looking for, leave the page open.
- Look at the dependences of each package, and open the webpage for all of them which are in your LIST.
- Use documentation (or your brain) to understand that dependences must be installed before the package that needs them.
- From there, use your logic to deduct the right order : *each dependence must be installed before the package they depend on, and that even if multiple packages need only one dependence. The dependence need to be installed only once, then it's good to all packages needing it. => That means you start by installing the dependences that don't need any other package from your list, then proceed gradually until all packages are installed.*

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do:

```
apt-get download ubuntu-minimal:i386=1.307 network-manager-gnome:i386=0.9.8.0-1ubuntu5.1 \
network-manager:i386=0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22 dnsmasq-base:i386=2.66-4ubuntu1 \
iputils-arping:i386=3:20121221-1ubuntu1 libgnome-bluetooth11:i386=3.8.1-2ubuntu2 \
libnetfilter-conntrack3:i386=1.0.3-1 libmnl0:i386=1.0.3-3 \
libnm-glib-vpn1:i386=0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22 libnm-gtk0:i386=0.9.8.0-1ubuntu5.1 \
libnm-glib4:i386=0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22 libnm-gtk-common=0.9.8.0-1ubuntu5.1 \
libnm-util2:i386=0.9.8.0-0ubuntu22 wpasupplicant:i386=1.0-3ubuntu2.1 libreadline5:i386=5.2+dfsg-2
```

Then move or copy the files and install them with `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Comment: Doesn't `dpkg` need to follow the right order ? Is it smart enough, like `apt-get`, to check the other .deb to see if there is the dependences it needs ?

Comment: dpkg just stacks all the packages and starts installing stuff, also the shell just pass all the packages names. Try using `echo *.deb` and you see exactly what dpkg sees. dpkg doesn't need order of installation as long as you supply all the necessary packages. If you check dpkg execution by apt you will see just `dpkg --unpack --auto-deconfigure /long/list/of/packages.deb /without/any/specific/order.deb`

Comment: That's sweet ! Well, I wasted my time answering so specifically to the question :D

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to Braiam and MrVaykadji, and everybody else, for your fast and clear help to help to solve this!!

To make this post useful also for other linux-users with similar problems I decided to write here how I solved it.

First of all, after realizing something really went wrong using the 'purge' command, I checked /var/log/dpkg.log . I made a copy of the log-file and looked in the copied file, being guided by the recorded time and date in the file. I deleted every entry in the log-file before the date/time that I messed things up (make sure you're in the copied log-file!!) Then I did a text-search for "remove" and as such it highlighted entries of "remove" in front of all packages that had been mistakenly removed. I copied the name of the packages.

With the help of Braiam and MrVaykadji I downloaded all the missing/removed packages from packages.ubuntu.com. I actually learned just now that I can actually paste text in my eterm terminal by pressing , so the easiest way to quickly get all the packages is creating a text file in which you copy all the missing packages seperated by spaces. Preceed in the text-file with "apt-get download" -> "apt-get download example-package:i386=1.307 another-package:i386=1.307" (With the command apt-get --help if found out the packages will be downloaded to the current folder, so make sure that with your terminal you're in the folder where you would like to download/save the packages, in my case a usb-stick)

I plugged the usb-stick in my "purged" pc, went to the right folder, selected 'Tools > open current folder in terminal' and in the terminal I used shift+insert to paste "sudo dpkg -i " from a text file I included on my usb-stick (necessary in my case because my network broke down).

That solved it :) I did have to get some additions packages and reconfigure some files with the command "dpkg --configure " but with that done it's all working fine again :)

again thanks a lot to Braiam and MrVaykadji!! :)

Comment: N.B. I'm new here on the forum.. Is there any way to change the status of this post to solved?? :)